# Getting error while integrating activemq with datadog agent

Tags: activemq-classic, datadog

I am trying to integrate activemq with datadog. I have modified /Users//.datadog-agent/conf.d/activemq_58.yaml.

Changes are:

> instances:
>    - host: localhost
>      port: 8161
>       user: admin
>       password: admin

activemq is running in localhost at default port with jmx enabled.

Restarted datadog agent 
I could see error after running info command. Error is

> activemq_58
>
> ---
>
> ```
> - initialize check class [ERROR]: 'mapping values are not allowed in >this context\n  in "<byte string>", line 4, column 10'
> ```

Can anybody suggest that why I am getting this error?

Comment: sounds like a YAML configuration error. YAML's very finicky, maybe try pasting the content in a yaml validator? https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator

Answer (score 0):

is your `activemq_58.yaml` all in one line like that? You probably want it to be more like this:

```
instances:
    - host: localhost
      port: 8161
      user: admin
      password: admin
```

Comment: Its same as you have mentioned (not in one line). The above issue is resolved but getting other issue.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/datadog-agent info and getting below error                                                     activemq_58
    -----------
      - instance #activemq_instance [ERROR]: 'Cannot connect to instance localhost:8161 java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]' collected 0 metrics
      - Collected 0 metrics, 0 events & 0 service checks